# How many simultaneous clients can be handled in a Google App Engine application using the Channel API?

Tags: google-app-engine, cordova, channel-api

I am building a mobile app using the Channel API (in phonegap). However, I also want to create a browser based client. My question is:

How many simultaneous clients can be handled in a Google App Engine application using the Channel API?

Comment: Two questions: will your mobile app wrap a browser control to create an endpoint? Second: what do you mean by "how many devices?" Do you mean "how many simultaneous clients?"

Comment: Sorry... yeah you are right its clients! AND I am using phonegap for the mobile clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of simultaneous clients you can have is governed by the number of tokens you request and the duration of each token. By default, tokens are good for two hours and you can request 60 tokens per minute, so you can have 60 * 60 * 2 = 7200 active clients at any one time.

If you need more, contact us here: http://support.google.com/code/bin/request.py?&contact_type=AppEngineCPURequest and we can boost your quotas significantly.